# Git config change issue: Cannot push commits because of server-side receive hook

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, tortoisegit, git-config

I did a Git Commit and then had to make some config changes (specifically a "email" related config)
So there seems to be some pre-commit hook/check added by my org which checks that the email address should match some specific value

Now I did update the "email" to the expected value and am trying to Push now. However, I am still getting the error (Also shows the earlier/old value);
Invalid Email for commits

If I go to Tortoise Git > Settings and click Edit global .gitconfig, I see the updated value

If I do

```
git config --list
```

from my project folder (from where I am trying to Push), I can see that it has the updated value
Also checked the .gitconfig in a couple of other places (Documents) and it also has the updated value.
My question is why is Git seeing the old value and not the updated value when I am trying to Push.

**P.S:** I primarily use TortoiseGit, but I did try to run the "git push" command manually as well with the same issue.

Comment: I think you get the errors for older commits you're pushing. Maybe check in the log the email for all commits (you could add the column email to the log in tortoisegit)

Answer (score 1):

Your company did not employ a commit hook, but a server side receive hook.

Your email address is stored as meta-data for all your commits and every time you try to push new commits to your server that meta data is checked.

The only way to change that meta-data (for your unpushed commits) is to perform a rebase.

For this open the log dialog, select the latest pushed commit and select Rebase onto this commit. On the rebase dialog select force (as you want to alter this history on the very same branch) and mark all commits as "Edit". Start the rebase and click on "Edit/split commit". - When committing select "Set author" on the commit dialog and put your current data there.

Comment: @testndtv Please consider to uvote/accept this answer if it helped you or leave a comment on what's still missing.